# I Recieved an Error Trying to Add A Synonym, Why?

Tags: support

I tried to propose a tag synonym for ww2, but I received the error "Only moderators can propose version specific synonyms".  I thought after 1200 rep, you were able to propose tag synonyms.  Does anyone know what this means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like we have a bug with [detecting tags that apply to different versions of software](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121457/version-specific-tag-validation-on-tag-synonym-page) - an artifact of the Stack Exchange platform being born out of programming Q&A. :)

I've passed it up the chain to the dev team.

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to be 1250, maybe your rep was not synchronized?  That's about the only thing I have seen before, where what I see as Rep was not quite what I was gettng for tools but an hour later all was fine.

Try again and if you get an error let us know.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I thought.  I'll update this when it becomes more clear.

Comment: Tried again.  Recieved this error:
*Failed to propose synonym:

Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators*

Comment: heh...must be a permissions thing.  If you let me know the synonym, I'd be happy to add it.

Comment: Yeah, its "wwii".  I still have no idea what a "version specific synonym" is.  I assume it must be more privileged than a run-of-the-mill synonym.

Comment: I think its the fact there was already a tag for wwii that was used on two questions, since one was already closed I did the merge so the synonym now exists anyway.  And two questions got updated.  So all good.